# Subcategory listing issue using float left

Tags: html, css

Hey I want that my SubCat4 should be listed below SubCat1 and SubCat5 should be below SubCat2 I have tried many things but couldn't get it..

Here is my HTML code..

```
<div class="sub_menu">
<ul>
    <li>SubCat1<span class="icon icon-arrow_down"></span></li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>SubCat2<span class="icon icon-arrow_down"></span></li>
    <li>By Author</li>
    <li>By Title</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>SubCat3<span class="icon icon-arrow_down"></span></li>
   <li>By City</li>
</ul>
<ul>
     <li>SubCat4<span class="icon icon-arrow_down"></span></li>
     <li>Fiction Books</li>
      <li>Non Fiction Books</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>SubCat5<span class="icon icon-arrow_down"></span></li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>E-Books Vs. Paper Books</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>General Advice on Books</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>Ten Best Authors / Poets</li>
    <li>More...</li>
</ul>
```

You can get the CSS and code in my jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/uiupdates/yac70mhw/1/

Pls help..
thankx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use floats here, but inline-block.

```
.sub_menu {
    display: block;
    margin: 15px 15px 15px 0px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 844px;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
}
 .sub_menu ul {
    border: medium none;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 15px;
    width: 251px;
    padding:0;
}
```

**Example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/yac70mhw/3/

Comment: I can use the min-height but am not sure about how many <li> will be there in Subcat1...Using your CSS I got the desired output but if SubCat1 has more <li> element then Subcat5 also come done and take the min-height of SUBCAt1 I dont want that..

Answer (score 0):

Use the `clearfix`
insert this after the 3rd `<ul>`
`<div class="clearfix"></div>`
And finally in the css -

```
.clearfix {
clear: both;
}
```